# Post-processing tips questions allowed?

Tags: discussion, questions

Recently Sebastian.b posted [this](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4416/how-do-i-achieve-this-post-process-effect) question. I personally think that the question is fine and I am excited to see this kind of question. However, he mentions that he could ask the same question for many other styles, and that this concerns him that the question is not appropriate.

As I said, I like his question, and it made me want to ask my own about another style.

So is it ok? I think that this would be very useful, so I am in support of this.

Thanks to Sebastian for getting the ball rolling, and thanks to the rest of you for your time.

Answer (score 4):

I'm open to this sort of question; so far there have been a lot of "camera craft" and little on "post processing". There was the [optical equivalent](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/4333/21) asked yesterday, which appears to have been well received, so I see no reason to apply similar analysis to post processing where there is an answerable question ("so how can I replicate this effect" is better than "what should I do to make this not suck")

Comment: ok great! Now I just cant ask my "Why do my prints suck?" question! lol! Thanks for the response.

Comment: @BBischof Even that would be reasonable if you clarified *how* they suck (over saturated/too dark/colour cast/etc)

Comment: hehe thanks, (let's just hope the how isn't composition!)

Answer (score 1):

IMO, **yes**, that's totally on-topic (similar sentiments to @Rowland, but I'll be more explicit).